# Are review queues supposed to include answers to my own question?

Tags: support, review

While browsing the *First Posts* review queue on Super User, I came across a [familiar looking answer](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/670659).

[image: Review Queue - Familiar looking answer]

I sit there and wonder why this answer might look familiar. I'm fairly certain I've just recently seen it before. Maybe seeing the question's author might remi...

[image: Question author]

Oh. It's an answer to a question I just asked an hour ago.

**Is this intentional? Are we supposed to see answers to our own questions in review queues?**

Comment: Why do you expect that answers to your own question are filtered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is in the First Posts review queue of Super User then I suspect that it is there purely because it is the first post on Super User by the user.

Since you have the privilege to review first posts on Super User, and asking questions on Super User, it would seem likely that on occasion you may see answers to your own questions there.